# Is there a way to type in a File Upload box with Protractor?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, automated-tests, protractor

When the File Upload window pops up with the cursor already focused on the field, is there a way to make Protractor sendKeys to that, instead of going through the whole absolute path file select stuff?

I'm using AngularJS/Jasmine framework. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, *the upload dialog you see is not under selenium's control.* You have to avoid this popup being opened in the first place.

A common approach is to send keys containing an absolute path to a file to upload to a specific `input` with `type="file"`.

Comment: ahh okay that makes sense. I've done some google searching and found the code other people have used to do what you're describing, but I hadn't gotten that it was avoiding the dialog. I don't really know what I'm doing enough to easily adapt the code to work for me. That's why I was trying to do the sendKeys thing. I think my path and getting to the file is where I'm messing up. Not even sure about that. I'll keep working on it. Thanks!

Comment: @Defpotec2020 okay, feel free to create a separate question providing more details about what are you doing, what code are you executing and what do you see in the browser. Thanks.

Comment: My test is failing, but fortunately/unfortunately the file upload is not the reason anymore. Your revelation was all it took to get that part working right. For the record, the file upload code I used is at https://gist.github.com/thekarel/9169612.